# How do I declare strings of data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, declare

I have a long code that is creating financial accounting data.

The code uses multiple unions to breakout data to different company groupings.

There are 5-6 account groupings that are reference multiple times.

Anytime there is a change to the groupings I have to go through the code and change it in each location.

An example of the string is below:

```
Where account in ('81000', '82000','87000','83600','67000') 
and account like '814%'
```

Is there anyway to put this in a declare or just internally link to that code in other where statements?

Comment: `Where account in ('81000', '82000','87000','83600','67000') and account like '814%'` will never match anything, should that be `or`? In any event why don't you add the account group to the account table?

Comment: Depending on the setup, you could create a 'search table' for the groupings, then use a sub-query.  Otherwise, you're going to need to use dynamic sql, and some form of lookup...

Comment: Yes it should have been an or sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do what you describe, which is best will depend on your exact needs.

First and simplest is to use variables.

```
declare @account1 int; set @account1 = 81000;
declare @account2 int; set @account2 = 82000;
declare @account3 int; set @account3 = 87000; /* and so forth*/
```

It's not clear from your question whether this is being called from a front end app, if it is, you can use sql parameters to set the account values.

```
string cmd =' declare @account1 int; set @account1 = @acount1In;
              select columnslist from accounts  where account in (@account1)
              union
              select columnslist from accounts  where account in (@account1)
            ';
```

Secondly, you could put the values either into a temporary table or table variable.

```
declare @accountIds table (account int);
insert into @accountIds values(81000);

select columnlist from accounts where account in (select account from @accounts);
```

Finally, if this is really the same expression done multiple times, you might consider using a common table expression.

```
;using cte as (select columnlist from accounts where account in (81000, 87000)
)
select columnlist from cte inner join table2 on a=b 
union 
select columnlist from cte inner join table3 on a=c
```